# What would be the Mediatype for Base64 encoded string?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, web-services

I have a rest endpoint where the response is added in the object, that object is converted to Json string and that jaon string is finally converted to Base 64 encoded string. I was wondering what would be the Mediatype in this case?

This is for the tag

@Produces(MediaType.Application.Json)

Or should it be url encoded?

Comment: JSON is already plain text, why are you base64 encoding it?

Comment: The reason is to add the encoding to the sensitive data. Would it make sense to encode ut here? Or should I retort back to sending json as plain text

Comment: Encoding sensitive data to base64 provides no protection.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific media type for Base64 encoded JSON. It's a very odd case (JSON is serialised and can be sent as-is, there's no need to encode it.) You definitely shouldn't use `application/json` as what you're sending isn't actually JSON.

If you really want to do it, the only sensible type I think you can use in this situation is the default `APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM`. I don't think you'll find a more specific one that makes sense.